# Text will not wrap within Div. Have tried using word-wrap: break-word;

Tags: css, web, word-wrap

My body text leaves the container div when the browser window is resized. I've tried using both using word-wrap: break-word; and overflow-wrap: break-word; and both have not worked. Pulling my hair out. Please help!

[Here is the live site.](http://www.chrispicco.ca)

Comment: A question should contain code to reproduce the problem. A link to a live site is enough – the question would lose meaning once the problem has been fixed on the live site.

Comment: Good point. New to this site. Once I figure out the source of this, I'll edit the question and add the code to reflect the environment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class ".hentry" that has a width of 750 on line 682 of your style.css?ver=3.7, that seems to be causing it to not shrink beyond that.  This is the line that incorporates the hentry class:
`<article id="post-18" class="post-18 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">`

Comment: Thank you very much for point that out to me! This was indeed the fix.

<article id="post-18" class="post-18 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">

This included the class hentry.

I changed the set width to width: auto; and it work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

use this css i have tested in mozilla firefox its working for firefox but not sure about other browsers.

```
 text-align: justify;
```